# multilabel classification for text with scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

I'm trying to create a multilabel classifier with scikit-learn to texts.
I am new to scikit learn and I do not know if it is possible to create a classifier for text.
My intention is to use SVM multilabel, but do not know if I have to adapt the texts to train the classifier or else you can work directly with texts.
Does anyone know some documentation on this subject?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refer to this example: [Classification of text documents using sparse features](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/document_classification_20newsgroups.html)

which can give you exposer to not only multiclass but also basic text mining details of:

- Vectorizer and hashing
- Feature selection
- Handling Sparse Data
- Comparing different basic models